# How to access next and previous keys in an OrderedDict in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an OrderedDict structure that is ordered through key sorting, in the following fashion:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

my_regular_dict = {
    '1': 'first value',
    '2': 'second value',
    '3': 'third value'
}

my_ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(my_regular_dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

In `my_ordered_dict` I would like to be able to call a method that given a key, returns the next one, but in Python 3.5, something like this:

```
>>> my_ordered_dict.get_next_key('1')
'2'
```

I know that previously in python 3.4 and others you could access the map and just grab the key with no problem, but that changed with the new C based implementation in python 3.5, leaving no possibility to access private methods.

I've been dragging my head with this for a few hours now and I can't get around it, is there any way at all to do this, or am I doing this just wrong?

Comment: `k = list(my_ordered_dict.keys())` then `print(k[k.index("1")+1])` is that what you mean?

Comment: Can't you just keep track of the index (number) of your keys (strings)?  That would be way faster than searching for the key in the list of keys just to find its successor.

Comment: OrderedDict only handles very, very limited ordering use cases - little more than ensuring the order is actually there. For anything more complicated, tracking order manually is likely to be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably not very efficient because of the `index` method (could be improved with `bisect` since the keys are sorted in your case), and also because of the creation of a list at each call (which could be avoided by iterating on the keys with a loop using a memory effect to compare to the previous element & return the current one) but here's my proposal:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def gnk(self, k):
    l = list(self.keys())
    i = l.index(k)
    if i<len(l)-1:
        return l[i+1]
    else:
        raise Exception("last key")

OrderedDict.get_next_key = gnk

my_regular_dict = {
    '1': 'first value',
    '2': 'second value',
    '3': 'third value'
}

my_ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(my_regular_dict.items()))  # no need for custom key, keys cannot be equal

print(my_ordered_dict.get_next_key('1'))
```

It adds a method to `OrderedDict` class, which creates the keys as list (not very efficient, I admit) then looks for the index of the key and takes the next index.

Maybe not what you're looking for, since it's `O(n)` without `bisect`, that you can use only if the keys are sorted using lexicographical order.

EDIT: method using `bisect`, `O(log(n))` complexity (but the keys 2 list is still `O(n)`:

```
import bisect

def gnk(self, k):
    l = list(self.keys())
    i = bisect.bisect_left(l,k)
    if i<len(l)-1:
        if l[i]!=k:
            raise KeyError(k)
        return l[i+1]
    else:
        raise Exception("last key")
```

As some comments hint at, the solution may not work in Python 3.6+, so a better way to do this would be to implement a custom dictionary class using `bisect` for lookup, and a real `list` for the keys. Writing such a class is doable (but will take time to finetune if you *really* want to emulate a dictionary closely) but beyond a concise answer.

Comment: I... it seems that I'm overloaded for the day. Yeah, that works, I didn't even think about it, thanks!

Comment: the bisect version is probably faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jean-François, I'll accept the answer asap :)

Comment: -1 Your bisect version is not O(log(n)), it's still O(n).  And the first way you've shown won't work in the current version of Python.

Comment: thanks for your kind downvote. It's clearly stated that this isn't optimal because of the copy of the keys. Something better to propose?

Comment: Well, it didn't clearly state that when I cast a vote, you edited it in afterwards.  And you haven't yet addressed the problem of contributing a method to `OrderedDict` class, what you've written just won't work in current builds of Python, it's gonna raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: you mean that it'll break in python 3.6 because `OrderedDict` is `dict` & read-only? ok, seems that OP needs a custom dict with an internal `bisect` for key lookup. Not sure if I want to write that one.

Comment: It will break even in 3.5 (which the OP said they're using) if the build is correct.  The Python implementation is only a fallback (see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L296-L300)), and the C implementation can not be monkeypatched.

Comment: @wim So far the first solution provided by Jean-François is working in python 3.5.3 (I haven't tested the bisect because it doesn't provide a major difference since my datasets are quite small (< 100 elements)) but if someone comes with a better solution for the future, you're welcome! :)

Comment: v3.5.3 does have the C impl, so it sounds like [your build is getting an `ImportError` there](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.3/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L298) and you should probably look into that.  If you don't care that the code will break on other people's computers (and it might even break suddenly should you reinstall Python), then you can use this solution.